# Select all rows with smallest date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need help with SQL query. From **my_wl_table** , I need to select all rows, except following condition: if **session_id** is presented more than once (for example, **s1**), I need to select raw for this session id with lowest **first_trigger_hit_datetime** column:

*my_wl_table:*

```
**session_id  |  first_trigger_hit_datetime  |  column1**  
s1            |         2018-06-04           |  T          
s2            |         2018-06-06           |  C     
s3            |         2018-06-02           |  T     
s1            |         2018-06-09           |  T
```

*Output that I need*:

```
s1            |         2018-06-04           |  T          
s2            |         2018-06-06           |  C     
s3            |         2018-06-02           |  T
```

So, for sessions, that have multiple entries, I need to select only one row with smallest datetime value. Last row (with 2018-06-09 datetime), should not be included into output result.

Comment: Can you share your code attempt with us? What did you write that did not produce the correct output?

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `first_value()`:

```
select distinct session_id,
       min(first_trigger_hit_datetime) over (partition by session_id) as first_trigger_hit_datetime,
       first_value() over (partition by session_id order by first_trigger_hit_datetime desc) as column1
from t;
```

Because this is only available as an analytic function, you need `select distinct`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, What does this  part means?:  first_value() over (partition by session_id order by first_trigger_hit_datetime desc) as column1

Comment: @Bilberryfm . . . https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_first_value.html.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it would work.

```
select session_id,
       first_trigger_hit_datetime,
       column1
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over 
                 ( partition by session_id
                       order by first_trigger_hit_datetime
                 ) as rn 
          from t
       ) tmp
 where rn = 1;
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM t
 ORDER
    BY row_number() over 
         ( partition by session_id
               order by first_trigger_hit_datetime
         ) as rn
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES; -- Double check this does what you want in case of a tie on {session_id, first_trigger_hit_datetime}
```